# Passing parameters to and calling a method without a constructor

Tags: java, method-call

I have a homework assignment where I have to pass a 2D array to a method, that method takes a 2D array as a parameter and prints out the table. I have the table working fine, the problem is I cannot figure out how to call this method from my main method without a constructor.

I know the obvious solution is to simply make a constructor method first and use that but, I unfortunately cannot because of the requirements of the homework.

Can anyone please just tell me how I can call this method, pass the param and have it print out the table, from the main method WITHOUT making a constructor method? Thank you.

As is I am getting: `pgm1.java:75: error: non-static method arrays(int[][]) cannot be referenced from a static context

                                 arrays(tenBy);
                                 ^
1 error`

```
public class pgm1
```

{

```
public void arrays(int[][] userArray)
{

    int rowTotal = 0;
    int colTotal = 0;
    int allTotal = 0;       


    //For loop to populate array, find total values of all odd rows,
    //all even columns, and all total index values
    for (int i = 0 ; i < userArray.length ; i++)
    {

        for (int h = 0 ; h < userArray.length ; h++)
        {           
            userArray[i][h] = i * h;
            System.out.printf("%3d" , userArray[i][h]);

            //Running total of all index values
            allTotal += userArray[i][h];

            //Running total of all odd rows
            if (i % 2 == 1)
                rowTotal += userArray[i][h];

            //Running total of all even columns
            if (h % 2 == 0)
                colTotal += userArray[i][h];                    
        }
        System.out.println();           

    }

    //Print all totals
    System.out.println("\n Total of odd numbered rows: " + rowTotal);
    System.out.println(" Total of even numbered columns: " + colTotal);
    System.out.println(" Total of all numbers: " + allTotal);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    //Creating 2D Array
    int[][] tenBy = new int[10][10];

    //arrays();

    arrays(tenBy);      

}
```

}

Comment: If I emphasize **non-static method**, what does that tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public void arrays(int[][] userArray)
```

to

```
public static void arrays(int[][] userArray)
```

[JLS-8.4.3.2. `static` Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) says (in part),

> A method that is declared `static` is called a class method.

and

> A method that is not declared `static` is called an *instance method*, and sometimes called a non-`static` method.

Comment: Thank you Elliot, I really appreciate it :)